# cannot click OK button in facebook login in android emulator

Tags: android, facebook, android-emulator, titanium-mobile

i'm working on an app in titanium studio that uses the facebook SSO to authenticate the user.

the odd issue we're having is that in the default android emulator, you can enter your username and password into the login overlay then you get to the confirm authorization page. fine, but you can't click `OK` or `Cancel` in the dialog, so the login never completes. the only click-able element on the page is the little `(X)` in the upper corner, which cancels the login. the console displays no errors at any time through this.

why this is strange: if i compile the app directly to my droid, it works perfectly. i can get logged in, look at my profile, whatever. i do not have the facebook app on my droid, but i installed it on the emulator thinking it might change the functioning. it didn't, it still won't let me click either button.

i realize that this is not a show-stopper type of bug, but it makes debugging via the emulator extremely problematic - so i was wondering if anyone else had run across/resolved this.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can tell, the emulator doesn't play well with the login overlay from facebook: in addition to the click events not being heard, we also noticed later that some of the facebook button and image resources were not being loaded.

side note: in addition to the above facebook-related problems, we were also experiencing a failure to initialize the emulator or failure to install the apk to a running emulator, both for no apparent reason, roughly a 50% of the time.

solution: i gave up and switched our team to the genymotion emulator. it works perfectly every time. we haven't had a problem since.